# Compiling ecma script 6 with Node traceur

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ecmascript-6, traceur

I can't seem to get the tutorial to work: https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/CompilingOffline

- I installed Node
- I create a file here: `C:/xampp/htdocs/angular/laravel/app/script/controllers/home-controller.js`
- I want to compile to here: `C:/xampp/htdocs/angular/laravel/public/scripts/controllers/home-controller.js`
- I open up Node, and run the following command:

  `$ ./traceur --out C:/xampp/htdocs/angular/laravel/public/scripts/controllers/home-controller.js --script C:/xampp/htdocs/angular/laravel/app/script/controllers/home-controller.js`

It puts `"..."` in the command line.

I close Node and re-open...

I then put it without the `$` and it says:

```
Invalid REPL keyword
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would be good to see your home-controller.js code.  Also, looks like you are not using canonical naming for your file.  It should be called homeController.js (and its associated template should be called home-controller.html or home-controller.tpl.html).

Comment: You are not supposed to actually input the `$`, it symbolizes your prompt. You are working in Windows, I assume?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg - the home-controller.js contains the example in the tutorial.

Comment: I renamed the file and placed new name in cmd line, it didn't work... same message.

the tpl.html is not in the tutorial so i'm unsure why that would be the problem?

Comment: what's all this npm install traceur stuff.. I don't get it... why they just don't give us an install file and a gui, <sigh>

Comment: I don't see any angular-traceur tutorial at the page you linked to.

Comment: I think I've missed the point then :) Do you have perhaps a simpler tutorial? Or a perhaps a better guide for the components I will have to use to make this work?

Comment: Cedric, I bailed on it. I'll definitely try this later! Thanks for you time man!

Answer (score 1):

in fact you have to install traceur globally so you can use it from the command line.
you need to install it like this

from the command line of a cmd prompt launch the following

```
  your path>npm install traceur -g
```

see the "-g". then you must not start node but use traceur from the command prompt itself

```
  your path>traceur --dir ./src ./ dest
```

where src contains your es6 files and dest will be the result